# Convention for $(-1)^x$ in closed form expressions ($x\in \Bbb{R}$)

Tags: terminology, convention

I'm trying to find the closed form expression from a question but I'm debating whether I should include $(-1)^x$ in it, which would make the question significantly easier. My problem with the question is that $(-1)^x$ becomes complex when $x$ is not an integer, i.e. most of its graph "vanishes". I'm not sure if something like this would be allowed in a high school level question but then again, there's no reason for it to not be allowed because other "vanishing" graphs like $\sqrt{x}$ and $\log_ax$ are standard and accepted.

What is the convention for $(-1)^x$ (given $x\in \Bbb{R}$) in closed form expressions? Is it considered an accepted part of closed form expressions even though it changes between being real and complex?

Thank you.

Note: To make it clearer, the question I'm referring to is part of the current IYMC so I decided to not include the question itself. Also, this is recreational work outside of school so I have no teacher to talk to. I wrote that the question is "high-school level" because of this but I'm not sure if it is.

Note 2: The question doesn't suggest anything about the answer, using $(-1)^x$, $x\in \Bbb{R}$ was a plan that I devised and I just wanted to know what the common practice for it is.

Comment: It probably depends on the context and whether your teacher is okay with something like that, to be honest. Some teachers are okay with the implementation of outside knowledge, others not - or for all we know, it's knowledge you're meant to demonstrate in the problem, you know? My gut assumption would be to just leave it as $(-1)^x$ unless there's a particularly noteworthy reason to the contrary - or at the worst, ask your teacher and see what they think. I just think this is too context-dependent for us to give a proper answer.

Comment: but the real parts of the graphs of $\sqrt{x}$ and $\log_a x$ are connected, however the graph where $(-1)^x$ is real- valued is disconnected. This complicate to show that in high school. It is more simple just show the complex-valued version of $(-1)^x$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I think you got the wrong impression, I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @Masacroso I will ditch this idea then because I'm sure completely complex numbers are too advanced for the the question at hand.

Comment: I wonder what kind of problem this is. If it needs $(-1)^x$ for $x$ not integer, then that would mean to me one of three things: either complex values are allowed, in which case there is no problem, or, that $x$ is going to be taken from a rather peculiar domain so that $(-1)^x$ has at least one real value - but one that would sound very strange and of course you say $x \in \mathbb{R}$, or thirdly, that the imaginary parts will cancel - and in that case you should then be able to express instead with something involving $\cos(\pi x)$ and/or $\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer You may find the question paper yourself easily. I found out about it through the recent meta thread but I'm a little worried if my question is within bounds of the rules. (And I also feel like the quality of the question isn't very well.) Anyway, I edited my question yet again to include more info. I planned the approach involving $(-1)^x$ myself, it is not asked by the question.

Comment: @Typo : I think I see what thread and what question. I do not see why the domain must necessarily be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer It's to include the irrational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In calculus context the function $a^x$ is defined for $a>0$ even if the expression is well defined also when $a\le 0$ for particolar values of $x\in \mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ as for example $(-1)^\frac13=-1$.